# Unable to get the file path name after randomising

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

***Functionality:***

An array of image file path element will be randomised, and randomised image will append to the image tag.

***Issue:***

I have randomised the array of image element and when I console.log the randomised image, it returns the index of the array. At this point, the returned appended image error msg will be "lib/PAGE08/1" cannot be found, error404.

Hence, I used parseInt() method on the randomised element. However, it did not return the image path name, but still returned the index of the randomised element:

Meaning:

randomised method : `var randomCookies = Math.floor(Math.random() * goodcookies.length);`

when I console.log `console.log("randomCookies: "+ randomCookies);`, it returns the index, for example: 1, which points to the index 1 of the array "goodcookies"

I have tried to use parseInt() to convert the index back to the file path name: `showgoodcookies = parseInt([randomCookies.length]);` and when I console.log(), it is still showing the index.

Code:

```js
var goodcookies = ["lib/PAGE08/Nutrients.png", "lib/PAGE08/BlueNutrients.png", "lib/PAGE08/RedNutrients.png"];
var showgoodcookies = "";


function spawnGood() {
  //Randomise cookies
  var randomCookies = Math.floor(Math.random() * goodcookies.length);
  console.log("randomCookies: " + randomCookies);
  showgoodcookies = parseInt([randomCookies.length - 1]);
  console.log("showgoodcookies: " + showgoodcookies);

  var goodNutrient = document.createElement("img");
  goodNutrient.id = "test1";

  //goodNutrient.src = "lib/PAGE08/Nutrients.png";
  goodNutrient.src = showgoodcookies;
}
```

Hence, I do require help, as in what went wrong when I tried to use parseInt() to convert the index back to the file path name of the image.

Comment: Use the index to get the element from the original array -   `showgoodcookies = goodcookies[randomCookies];`

Comment: @OriDrori, Thanks!

Comment: @OriDrori You should've posted your answer as an answer, since it is an answer, and comments aren't the place for answers (hint: the answer section is a good place for answers)

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. However, this is an answer without any real value expect for the OP, and posting it as an answer is a bit of an overkill for me.

Comment: @OriDrori - I guess you're right... Hmm. Answers are more than just solutions. I'm sorry for my snarky comment.

Comment: @Andrew . no worries. Next time phrase it as a question. After all it's just a a Q/A site, not the USA elections :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`randomCookies` isn't an array, it's an integer. You can't get its length. Your line should be:

```
showgoodcookies = goodcookies[randomCookies];
```